# Adding button in navigation bar showing only in current view. How to set for All views?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an navigation controller, I have pushed two views into that. I want to show a button in navigation bar, which should be shown in all views. But when I'm trying like this...

```
UIButton *button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo-57.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(-2, 0, 57, 57)];

UIBarButtonItem *btnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
root_obj_ab.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnItem;
```

It is adding in the local view where I am writing the code. How to set the button for all views?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about creating a custom view controller which has this button and then make all your view controllers as subclasses of that custom one?

Comment: This way looks good. If I were to implement, and I do not have a lot of customized buttons to use, I would do it like this.

Comment: Will subclassing navigation controller work in a similar way? or will all view controllers still possess different nav bars?

Comment: The way navigation controllers work is that the current view controller configures its navigation item so its properties become visible in the navigation controller navigation bar. So subclassing the navigation controller itself may be ok if you then do not use the navigationItem properties from each of your view controllers. Just check the navigation item class reference before doing so: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html

Answer (score 1):

If do not want to add the same button programatically to all of your navigation items, you should write a category on navigation bar where you need to add the button uibarbuttonitem.The same story like changing the the background color of the navigation bar prior to IOS 5.0.

Comment: it is about changing the background image but you can implicate it to adding button

Answer (score 0):

You must put this code in all view controllers in order to work in whole application.

Comment: If I do like you said. Do I need to write action for the button in each class?

Answer (score 0):

I think this question concerns more about design pattern. Ricard Pérez del Campo has addressed it in a subclass way. This would work good enough I think.

However, maybe you want some similar buttons to function in the same way, but those buttons still have some differences. Then you could apply Creational Pattern for doing this, say  [Factory Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), or to use [Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Hope this would help you for your design.

To demonstrate sample, maybe you could do it like this:

```
// Code in a CustomButtonFactory class
    + (UIBarButtonItem *)getCustomBackButtonItemForTarget:(id)target selector:(SEL)sel
    {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo-57.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:target action:sel forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setFrame:CGRectMake(-2, 0, 57, 57)];

        UIBarButtonItem *btnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

        return btnItem;
    }
```

If you do not want to implement selector every time and pretty sure that each such a button would function in the same way, you could implement the method in your factory class.